# Python - How to Select a Point on a Map and Track it through Time?

Tags: python, arrays, time-series, mapping, python-xarray

I have a series of monthly latitude vs longitude maps made from an xarray.

The xarray follows the structure of: [date, latitude, longitude]

In the lat/lon placements, there are unique integers that identify blobs of varying pixel sizes (a blob is identified by the same integer repeated across all the pixels it is associated with; for example, a blob may be identified by the number "16" and may be made up of 20 pixels, which would all be labelled with "16"). I am looking to select a point on the map, extract the unique integer associated with that point, and find the number of pixels that make up the blob. Any recommendations?

Thank you. I've attached a sample of a March map to clarify what a map looks like (example: all of the pink blob is identified by the same number, in this case approximately 10).

[image: MarchMap]

Comment: If you present the shape and sample of the numpy data, you can expect a more answer.